# Using Auth0 ID to retrieve and update user info from MySQL

Tags: mysql, reactjs, authentication, auth0

I created a ReactJS web app with a “user profile” page where the logged user can save: name, surname, email and address. For the moment, every time I log-in and save the data a new object is created.

I would like each logged user to be linked to a single ID, namely Auth0 one, so that I can always retrieve and update the row of the right user in my MySQL database.

I tried to look for other similar questions and to see the documentation, but it's my first time with authentication and I haven't found anything specific about Auth0,so I apologize if it’s a trivial question or asked several times .